# libvulkan-dev and vulkan-tools

Tags: 22.04, vulkan

```
libvulkan-dev : Depends: libvulkan1 (= 1.3.204.1-2) but 1.2.131.2-1 is to be installed
vulkan-tools : Depends: libvulkan1 (>= 1.3.204.0-1) but 1.2.131.2-1 is to be installed
```

I get these errors in Ubuntu 22.04. Is there any solution?

Comment: Please include more details in your question - which command exactly gives this output? And please provide full output, not only a few lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)